# Zoom into group of elements with d3.js

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have an svg with multiple objects in it. On selecting a checkbox i would like to zoom into the appropriate objects. I've come to something like the code below but zooming and positions are still not accurate. Can some point me out how i could accomplish this?

```
  d3.selectAll('g.active')
    .each(function(d, i) {

      var bounds = this.getBoundingClientRect();
        boundsLeft.push(bounds.left);
        boundsRight.push(bounds.right);
        boundsTop.push(bounds.top);
        boundsBottom.push(bounds.bottom);
      });

      var top = Math.min.apply(Math, boundsTop);
      var bottom = Math.max.apply(Math, boundsBottom) ;
      var right = Math.max.apply(Math, boundsRight) ;
      var left = Math.min.apply(Math, boundsLeft);

      var bounds = [[left, top], [right, bottom]],
      dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
      dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
      x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
      y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
      scale = Math.max(0.6, Math.min(8, 0.9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height))),

      translate = [(width / 2) - (scale * x), (height / 2) - (scale * y)];

      vis.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(zoom.translate([((dx * -scale) + (width / 2)), ((dy * -scale) + height / 2)]).scale(scale).event);
```

Comment: would be beneficial if you implement a JSFiddle so we can test

Comment: yes sure. I made one here https://jsfiddle.net/2aoqv2r9/1/

Comment: I don't see an element with id of `takeA`.  If I click `takeB`, though, you just want to zoom and center that `g` in the svg?

Comment: ahh yes sorry. I fixed that type and added 'takeA' to a g element. I would like if i click the checkbox 'Obj A' that it zoomes to the g-element A, the same for 'Obj B'. But if i have both checked it should take both elements into calculation and set the zoom appropriate for A and B.